# Dice game with two players, 3 die choices and cards

Tags: java, dice

I am trying to write code for a game that has a player and a computer roll dice until one, or both, reach 250( its possible for them to tie). The player and the computer can choose from 1 of 3 die choices. One - 24 sided tie, two - 10 sided die, or three - 6 sided die. There is a bonus for the 10 and 6 sided die if the die are all the same. There are 2 "lakes" where if the player lands in them the player has to go back to the lower number right before the beginning of the lake, there is also a muddy swamp where every move the player makes while in the swamp is cut in half. For every 10 spots (10, 20, 30, 40 ETC.) the player randomly draws a card. There are 11 different cards the player can randomly get:

1-4: player moves ahead a random amount from 1-6

5: player moves ahead a random amount from 4-11 (random 8 + 4)

6: player moves to where the other player is (see below)

7: player moves back to the beginning (moves to location 0)

8-9: player moves back a random amount from 1-6

10-11: player moves back a random amount from 4-11

I have a few problems. My first problem is that the die rolls do not change after every turn, they will remain the same. So if I choose 3 die I might get 3 random numbers, if I choose those die again I will get those same 3 numbers.

I also cannot seem to get the players die count to correctly update. If the player rolls 18 total points and the next turn he rolls 14 the count will go from 18 to 14.

My third problem is it seems like no matter what I do the print statement for the lakes,muddy patch and the winner announcement always print. I have tried a few different things and nothing seems to work.

I am new at code writing ( this is my 4th program written) and do not have extensive knowledge to know what is wrong. The code does not have to be expertly done, I just would like it to work properly. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
  /*This program will create a "Board" game. Each player can choose 
  from several different types of die. The computer and user will take 
  turns "rolling" a dice. There are several obstacles that can send one 
  of the players back. The goal is to get above 250*/

  import java.util.*;

  public class Project4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    //assigning variables
    int p1, p2;
    p1=p2=0;
    int spacesmoved  = 0;

    //Setting up the randomization of the 24 sided die
    int minimum1 = 1;
    int maximum1 = 24;
    Random rn1 = new Random();
    int range1 = maximum1 - minimum1 + 1;
    int die1 =  rn1.nextInt(range1) + minimum1;

    //Setting up the randomization of the 10 sided die
    int minimum2 = 1;
    int maximum2 = 10;
    Random rn2 = new Random();
    int range2 = maximum2 - minimum2+ 1;
    int die2 = rn2.nextInt(range2) + minimum2;
    int die22 = rn2.nextInt(range2) + minimum2;
    int die222 = rn2.nextInt(range2) + minimum2;

    //Setting up the randomization of the 6 sided die
    int minimum3 = 1;
    int maximum3 = 10;
    Random rn3 = new Random();
    int range3 = maximum3 - minimum3+ 1;
    int die3 = rn3.nextInt(range3) + minimum3;
    int die33 = rn3.nextInt(range3) + minimum3;
    int die333 = rn3.nextInt(range3) + minimum3;

    //Setting a loop for the players to take turns until one, or both, reach > 250
    while (p1 <= 250 && p2 <= 250) {
        {System.out.println(" Current positions.  Player: " + p1 + " Computer: " + p2);
            System.out.println("Which die would you like to roll? die1(1) = one 24-sided die, die2(2) = two 10-sided dice, die3(3) = three 6-sided dice: ");
       String diechoice = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();

       //Getting the die roll if the player chooses the 24 sided die
       if (diechoice.equals ("1")) {
           spacesmoved = (die1);
       System.out.println("Player rolled a " + die1);
       System.out.println("Player moves forward " + die1 +" spaces");
       p1+=spacesmoved;

       }

       //Getting the die roll if the player chooses the two 10 sided die
       if (diechoice.equals ("2")) { spacesmoved = (die2 + die22);
       System.out.println("First die is " + die2);//TESTTTT
       System.out.println("Second die is a " + die22);//TEST
       System.out.println(die2 + die22);//TESTTTTtttt
            if (die2 == die22); {
            spacesmoved = (die2 + die22 + die222);
            System.out.println("Player rolled doubles, player gets to roll a 3rd 10 sided die");
            System.out.println("Players 3rd dice roll is " + die222);
            System.out.println("Player moves forward a total of " + spacesmoved + " spots");
            p1 += spacesmoved;
        }
     //  player1spot = (currentspot + spacesmoved);
        }

       //Getting the die roll if the player chooses three 6 sided die
       if (diechoice.equals("3")) { spacesmoved = (die3 + die33 + die333);
       System.out.println("die 1 is " + die3);
       System.out.println("die 2 is " + die33);
       System.out.println("die 3 is " + die333);
       System.out.println("Player 1 moves forward a total of " + spacesmoved + " spots");
       { if (die3 == die33)
           if (die33 == die333)
           spacesmoved = ( spacesmoved * 2);

       p1 += spacesmoved;
       }}
       /*Setting up the lakes and muddy patch. If the player lands in a lake he goes back
       to the lower edge of the lake. If in the mud his moves are cut in half ONLY while in the mud */

       {if (spacesmoved >= (83) || spacesmoved <= (89)); spacesmoved = (82);
         System.out.println("Player landed in a lake, player goes back to space " + spacesmoved);
       if (spacesmoved >= (152) || spacesmoved <= (155)); spacesmoved = (151);
         System.out.println("Player landed in a lake, player goes back to space " + spacesmoved);
       if (spacesmoved >= (201) || spacesmoved <= (233)); spacesmoved = (spacesmoved / 2);
         System.out.println("Player landed in mud, players turns are cut in half until player gets out");
       }
       //Setting up the random cards if the player lands on a 10
       if (p1 % 10==0);
       { int minimum4 = 0;
       int maximum4 = 11;
       Random rn4 = new Random();
       int range4 = maximum4 - minimum4 + 1;
       int card =  rn4.nextInt(range4) + minimum4;

       //if player gets a card that moves them ahead a random number between 1-6
        if (card >=4);
           int minimum = 0;
           int maximum = 6;
           Random rn = new Random();
           int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
           int cardmove =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;
            p1 = cardmove;

       //if player gets a card that moves them ahead a random number between 4-11
        if (card == 5);
           int minimum5 = 4;
           int maximum5 = 11;
           Random rn5 = new Random();
           int range5 = maximum5 - minimum5 + 1;
           int cardmove5 =  rn5.nextInt(range5) + minimum5;
            p1 = cardmove5;
        //if player gets a card that moves them to the spot of the other player
        if (card == 6);
           p2 = p1;


        //if player gets a card that moves them back to 0 (moves location to 0)
        if (card ==7);
           p1 = 0;

        //if player gets a card that moves them back between 1-6 spaces
        if (card == (8) || card == 9);
           int minimum6 = 1;
           int maximum6 = 6;
           Random rn6 = new Random();
           int range6 = maximum6 - minimum6 + 1;
           int cardmove6 =  rn6.nextInt(range6) + minimum6;


        //if player gets a card that moves them back between 4-11 spaces
         if (card == (10) || card == 11);
           int minimum7 = 4;
           int maximum7 = 11;
           Random rn7 = new Random();
           int range7 = maximum7 - minimum7 + 1;
           int cardmove7 =  rn7.nextInt(range7) + minimum7;
       }
          //Setting up the computers turn

       System.out.println("Computers turn");
       {
         int minimum = 0;
         int maximum = 2;
         Random rn = new Random();
         int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
         int computersturn =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;

       //If computer randomly chooses a 24 sided die
         spacesmoved = (die1);
         System.out.println("Computer rolled a " + die1);
         System.out.println("Computer moved " + die1 +" spaces");
         p2+=spacesmoved;

       }

       //If the computer randomly chooses the two 10 sided die
         if (diechoice.equals ("die2")) { spacesmoved = (die2 + die22);
         System.out.println("First die is " + die2);//TESTTTT
         System.out.println("Second die is a " + die22);//TEST
         System.out.println(die2 + die22);//TESTTTTtttt
            if (die2 == die22); {
            spacesmoved = (die2 + die22 + die222);
            System.out.println("Computer rolled doubles, player gets to roll a 3rd 10 sided die");
            System.out.println("Computer 3rd dice roll is " + die222);
            System.out.println("Computer moves a total of " + spacesmoved + " spots");
            p2 += spacesmoved;
        }

        }

       //If the computer randomly chooses three 6 sided die
       if (diechoice.equals("die3")) { spacesmoved = (die3 + die33 + die333);
       System.out.println("die 1 is " + die3);
       System.out.println("die 2 is " + die33);
       System.out.println("die 3 is " + die333);
       System.out.println("Computer 1 moves a total of " + spacesmoved + " spots");
       { if (die3 == die33)
           if (die33 == die333)
           spacesmoved = ( spacesmoved * 2);

       p2 += spacesmoved;


       }




       //Setting the lakes and mud for the computer 

       if (spacesmoved >= (83) || spacesmoved <= (89)); spacesmoved = (82);
       System.out.println("Computer landed in a lake, player goes back to space " + spacesmoved);
       if (spacesmoved >= (152) || spacesmoved <= (155)); spacesmoved = (151);
       System.out.println("Computer landed in a lake, player goes back to space " + spacesmoved);
       if (spacesmoved >= (201) || spacesmoved <= (233)); spacesmoved = (spacesmoved / 2);
       System.out.println("Computer landed in mud, players turns are cut in half until player gets out");

       //Setting up the cards for the computer
       if (p1 % 10==0);
       { int minimum4 = 0;
       int maximum4 = 11;
       Random rn4 = new Random();
       int range4 = maximum4 - minimum4 + 1;
       int card =  rn4.nextInt(range4) + minimum4;

       //if computer gets a card that moves them ahead a random number between 1-6
        if (card >=4);
           int minimum = 0;
           int maximum = 6;
           Random rn = new Random();
           int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
           int cardmove =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;

       //if computer gets a card that moves them ahead a random number between 4-11
        if (card == 5);
           int minimum5 = 4;
           int maximum5 = 11;
           Random rn5 = new Random();
           int range5 = maximum5 - minimum5 + 1;
           int cardmove5 =  rn5.nextInt(range5) + minimum5;

        //if computer gets a card that moves them to the spot of the other player
        if (card == 6);
           p1 = p2;


        //if computer gets a card that moves them back to 0 (moves location to 0)
        if (card ==7);
           p1 = 0;

        //if computer gets a card that moves them back between 1-6 spaces
        if (card == (8) || card == 9);
           int minimum6 = 1;
           int maximum6 = 6;
           Random rn6 = new Random();
           int range6 = maximum6 - minimum6 + 1;
           int cardmove6 =  rn6.nextInt(range6) + minimum6;


        //if computer gets a card that moves them back between 4-11 spaces
         if (card == (10) || card == 11);
           int minimum7 = 4;
           int maximum7 = 11;
           Random rn7 = new Random();
           int range7 = maximum7 - minimum7 + 1;
           int cardmove7 =  rn7.nextInt(range7) + minimum7;
       }
       }    
      //Writing a final statment showing the winner, or if both tied.
       {     if (p1 > p2);
         System.out.println("Player 1 wins! Good job!");

       if (p2 >p1);
          System.out.println("Computer wins! Better luck next time!");

       if (p2 == p1);
          System.out.println("The game ends in a tie!");    
       }
    }

    }




}
```

}

Comment: Ask one question at a time

Answer (score 2):

Here are the things I noticed in relation to the three problems you mentioned:

**Problem number 1:**

You are setting the values of the dice at the very beginning of code execution. From that point on, you aren't changing them at all. That is the cause of the problem of always rolling the same numbers every turn. You might be thinking that every time you use `die1` or any of the other die variables, that it is re-executing the code at the top of your file, but it doesn't.

The code at the top of your file is executed only once and then the value stored in that variable is used for the rest of the program execution. Until you change it. So you would want something more like this:

```
//Getting the die roll if the player chooses the 24 sided die
if (diechoice.equals ("1")) {
    die1 = rn1.nextInt(range1) + minimum1;
    System.out.println("Player rolled a " + die1);
    System.out.println("Player moves forward " + die1 +" spaces");
    p1+=die1;
}
```

You would also need to change that in the other cases where the die is rolled.

Another benefit to doing it this way is that you really only need one random number generator. You don't actually need one for each die. You can use the same one for all die rolls.

**Problem number 2:**

I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong with die rolls, if there really is something going wrong there, but I did notice a few places where you'll want to change what is done to p1 and p2:

- When the player gets a card that moves them ahead, you'll want to use `+=` instead of `=`. i.e. `p1 += cardmove5` instead of `p1 = cardmove5`
- When the player gets a card that moves them back, it looks like you forgot to add the `p1 -= cardmove` statements.
- Also, make sure you have p1 and p2 in the right places. For example, I'm thinking that on the computer's turn, if they get the card to move them to the other player's spot, you meant to do `p2 = p1`, but instead you have `p1 = p2`. Same with the computer going back to 0. You have `p1 = 0`, but it seems like you would want `p2 = 0`. So just be careful about that. (Also be careful about copy paste. I'm guessing that's why that happened)

**Problem number 3:**

This problem looks like it's caused by the fact that you are using the `||` operator where you should be using `&&`. When you use `||`, you are effectively saying "or". So this first statement

```
if (spacesmoved >= (83) || spacesmoved <= (89))
```

reads as "if spacesmoved is greater than or equal to 83 *OR* less than or equal to 89"... Think about that for a second. Is there any number that is NOT greater than 83 OR less than 89? The answer is no. EVERY number will satisfy this condition. You would want to use `&&`, which means "and" like this:

```
if (spacesmoved >= (83) && spacesmoved <= (89))
```

"if spacesmoved is greater than or equal to 83 *AND* less than or equal to 89", which would only work for numbers between 83 to 89 inclusive.

You will also want to remove the semicolons after your "if" statements in that block and the other similar blocks. If you don't, the code inside those conditions won't get executed. That's actually a really tough bug to find when it happens.

Another thing to know is that when you want multiple things to be executed in an "if" condition, you must enclose it in curly braces `{}`, otherwise, only the first line will be included in the condition, and any following lines will be executed unconditionally. That is another fact that is causing this third problem.

One last thing is that you should try using "else if" and "else" statements. It will help your code flow make more sense. I'm not going to do all the work for you, but this code block should probably look more like this:

```
if (p1 >= (83) && p1 <= (89))
{
    p1 = (82);
    System.out.println("Player landed in a lake, player goes back to space " + p1);
}
else if (p1 >= (152) && p1 <= (155))
{
    p1 = (151);
    System.out.println("Player landed in a lake, player goes back to space " + p1);
}
else if (p1 >= (201) && p1 <= (233))
{
    spacesmoved = (spacesmoved / 2);
    p1 -= spacesmoved;
    System.out.println("Player landed in mud, players turns are cut in half until player gets out");
}
```

**Bonus Tip**

You're learning well, and it seems you are thinking of code flow pretty well. Just keep working and learning and you'll get it.

Look into your usage of parentheses. Using them doesn't hurt anything, but you are using them WAY more than you need.

Good luck! And keep learning!